# Angular 6 Grid Tiles line breaks

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have some grid tiles like this:

```
<mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="200px">
<mat-grid-tile [colspan]="1" [rowspan]="1">
<h3>Some Title</h3>
<p>Some text</p>
</mat-grid-tile>
...
</mat-grid-list>
```

I want the text to display like so:

```
Some Title
Some text
```

But it always displays as

```
Some TitleSome text
```

I've tried using `<br/>` as well as using css such as `white-space:pre; content:"\a"; white-space:pre-wrap` as well as some other things I am blanking on.

I feel like a moron for not getting this.

Here is a stackblitz showing the issue
https://angular-f9ficf.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out. It needed to be wrapped in div tags.

```
<mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="200px">
<mat-grid-tile [colspan]="1" [rowspan]="1">
<div>    
<h3>Some Title</h3>
<p>Some text</p>
</div>
</mat-grid-tile>
...
</mat-grid-list>
```